# Python package to create subfolder in folder of script using the package

Tags: python, python-3.x

*my aplogies for the complicated or poorly phrased title...*

I created a small package, which I made available through pipy.org. In this package, I scrape some data and I'd like to save the scraped data in the folder of the script that uses the package

I currently did this in the package:

```
DATA_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'data')
```

but when I install the package via `pip install mypackage` and use it like this in

> `/path/to/project/main.py`

```
from mypackage import MyPackage
...
mp = MyPackage()
print(mp.DATA_FOLDER)
```

it gives me `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mypackage/data` which is where the package is installed obviously.

But I want it to create the `data`folder in `/path/to/project/data`, is this possible? How would I get the path of the calling script?

I also tried to use a *relative* path with `DATA_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data')`, but then it makes a difference if I do this:

```
python /path/to/project/main.py
```

or this

```
cd /path/to/script && python main.py
```

first one creates the data folder whereever I call the script from, second one creates it "correctly".

What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
script_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
```

if you like `os.path` or

```
script_folder = pathlib.Path(sys.argv[0]).absolute().parent
```

for those who prefer `pathlib`.

This leverages the fact that the main script's file name is stored in [`sys.argv[0]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv). You can then create the path to the data folder relative to the folder the script resides in.

Comment: this looks promising BUT, this gives me `/path/to/project/main.py`, how do I get rid of `main.py` to join the path with `data`? //NVM, it is `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])), 'data')`